# How do I unlock the OSD on my acer XZ242Q?

Tags: display, desktop-computer, help-files

I've had this monitor for a little bit, played around with the settings a bit and messed up and now I can't get it unlocked, please lmk how, I've tried holding the button for 5 sec and 10 sec and it just says OSC locked.

Answer (score 0):

hold the joystick to the right for a few seconds